# Is `java -cp` simply an abbreviation for `java -classpath`?

Tags: java, classpath

On the commandline 
is `java -cp` simply an abbreviation for `java -classpath`?

(I seem to remember they may have different behaviour but can't find explicit documentation).

**UPDATE** Thanks (@AlBlue) for confirming that my memory was in fact correct and that they **used to be different**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They used to be different, but now they're the same (hence accepting both for compatibility). Originally, -classpath needed to have the classes.zip (Java 1.0/1.1) or rt.jar (Java 1.2+) in order to be able to function. Therefore, if you ran -classpath my.jar, it wouldn't work (since it wouldn't find java.lang.Object and friends). As a result, -cp was added which would append the classpaths/jars to the list, but not overwriting the classes.zip/rt.jar entry.

However, this behaviour changed sometime (1.4? 1.5?) so that you no longer needed to put entries on the 'system' classpath via -classpath, after which they were identical.

You could probably run commands from the 1.3 or 1.4 era (if you still have them) to verify when the change occurred.

Answer (score 8):

In Windows,

```
java -help
```

says under each

```
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
```

Looks pretty clear. They both does the same. So, yes, it's an alias.

Comment: Thanks - I read this but also noted that other commands mentioned synonyms explicitly. I also wasn't clear what "A" means and whether it specifically related to the last option

Comment: It's just English. Maybe the semicolon was a bit confusing. You should read it as "A semicolon separated list ...". In *nix (Unix, Linux and clones) it's by the way a colon `:`.

Comment: 'A' in that document is just an indefinite article at the beginning of a sentence :)

Comment: @Carl - Be gentle with him.  English is obviously not his first language :-)

Comment: The 'A' is for 'A semicolon list of directories' or, on Linux/Mac, 'A colon list of directories'. Unfortunately the use of the symbol, which can also be interpreted as a valid grammatical character in prose.

Answer (score 0):

See the [JDK Tools and Utilities](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/index.html) documentation for info on command line parameters.